# find lines that aren't matching in directory with grep

Tags: bash, shell

I have this bash script:

```
function getlist() {
       grep -E 'pattern' ../fileWithInput.js | sed "s#^regexPattern#\1 \2#" | grep -v :
   }

  getlist | while read line; do
  method=$(echo $line | awk '{ print $1 }')
  uri=$(echo $line | awk '{ print $2 }')
 `grep "$method" -vr  .
  #echo method: $method uri: $uri
  done
```

Question:
Currently I have many 'pattern' strings. How to check with directory and output only 'pattern' strings that doesn't match.

What I have example in fileWithInput.js:

```
'foo','bar','hello'.
```

~/repo/anotherDirectory:

```
'foo','bar'.
```

How to print only strings from fileWithInput.js that are not in /repo/anotherDirectory?
Final output have to be like this:

```
'hello': 0 matches.
```

Please help with grep command to do this. Or maybe you have another idea. Thanks for attention and have a nice day!

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do. However, your `getlist` function is very inefficient. `sed` could handle whatever you are trying to do with `grep` in that pipeline.

Comment: And where does the "directory" enter into the problem? As far as I can see, you are merely checking a single file. In that case, `grep -f file` might be what you are looking for.

Comment: I have strings in one file. I want to search this strings in another directory. And stings that not been found have to be output.

Comment: how are you searching for each of these strings? reading from an array?

Comment: I have to looking for from awk output

Comment: do you have multiple files in the directory?

Comment: What directory? There is no other directory. You are searching a single file which happens to be in a different directory. This is totally irrelevant.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `| sed "s#^regexPattern#\1 \2#" | grep -v :`?

Comment: @Sabutobi: You still haven't answered the question of how you are passing the `pattern`(s) as input to the function()

Comment: My question not in regex. I currenty have list of lines and don't know how to compare this lines with directory and output not matched lines. My input is result of sed and awk methods. That directory is with multiple files and directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

file1.txt

```
'foo','bar','hello'.
```

filem.txt

```
'foo','bar'.
```

with awk

```
  awk 'BEGIN{RS="[,\\.]"} NR==FNR{a[$0];next} {delete a[$0]} END{for(i in a){print i": 0 matches."}} ' filei.txt  filem.txt
```

code breakdown:

```
BEGIN{RS="[,\\.]"} # Record seperator , or .
NR==FNR{a[$0];next} # store values ina array a and skip from next process
{delete a[$0]} # delete from array if file1 exists in file2
END{
for(i in a){
    print i": 0 matches."} # print missing items
}
```

output:

```
'hello': 0 matches.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot about answer. In theory.. This question can be solved by grep or not?

Comment: i think not as it doesn't have delimeter

Comment: If use this construnction grep -r 'foo','bar','hello' | grep -v fileWithInput.js?